# Integration of CSS, Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have absolutely zero idea about web design.

If you go to http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/carousel-lightbox-tooltip.php you will find that the CSS, JavaScript and HTML codes have been separately mentioned. How do I integrate them? The CSS and JavaScript should go inside head tag?

Comment: How do you mean integrate them? Do you want to have all the code in the HTML-file?

Comment: Googling for html example, css example, javascript example could have taken less time than posting here

Comment: +1   I think the simplicity of the question is rather unique. Even when [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+integrate+html%2C+css%2C+and+javascript) now the results are very different and can be confusing to a newcomer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that they can be integrated in the **Head Section**.

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">

    /* Place the contents of the file.css here */

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

    // Place the contents of the file.js here.

</script>
```

Comment: For **importing** the files into the HTML file, Ana's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

inside the head of your .html file.

It would be even nicer if you could put your JavaScript not in the head, but at the end of the body tag.

This implies you have

- an .html file
- a folder called css which contains a style.css file where you have... all your CSS of course
- a folder called js which contains a script.js file where you have your JavaScript code

Comment: +1 for mentioning the folders, the little things we take for granted.

Answer (score 1):

If it is necessary you can have all the code in one file.

In a very simplified way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>/*javascript goes here*/</script>
        <style>/*css goes here*/</style>
    </head>
    <body>/*content goes here*/</body>
</html>
```